# Как правильно импортировать модули из node_modules для node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, webkit

Установил через `npm jquery`
Подключаю:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Получаю

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'

Не понимаю что не так.. В `node_modules` папка `jquery` присутствует, webstorm тоже видит этот модуль..

Если вручную перенести файл `jquery.min.js` в папку с исполняемым скриптом, то все норм импортируется. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На сколько я помню, node.js таким образом подгружает свои модули. В папку node_modules он посмотрит, если укажите следующее: var $ = require('./jquery');

Comment: @Евгений Шилин, К сожалению не  помогло.. Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './jquery'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что 
    `npm build`
в папке `jquery` вы не делали. `require` нужно делать именно без точки со слешем, т.к. модель присутствует в папке `node_modules`
Вообще на странице проекта в npm есть интсрукция, как это запустить.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.
И стеснясь спросить, зачем в ноде jquery?